# Listen to any changes (caused by code) in value of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can use some events like "oninput", "onchange" ... to detect if an HTML element change its value. But these events occurs only when user manually change the value (By keyboard, mouse...)

But sometimes HTML elements's values are changed by my code (not by users) or by form's reset() method and I also want to listen to these change events.

So how can I detect when a value of an element changes? (In all situations)

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`DOMSubtreeModified`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php) event

```
$('element').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  alert('changed');
});
```

*Depending of the version of jquery instead of `.on` can be `.bind`

Or you can work with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which detects changes in the DOM and is the most recommended.

Comment: The "DOMSubtreeModified" event doesn't work in Chrome and Safari :(

I think the Mutation Observer way can solve the problem but it's little complicated :)

Comment: @DucHoang Exactly, I even reinforced in the answer that would be the best option, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
document.ewatch=[];
watchEle=(id,callback)=>{
    var ii=document.ewatch.length;
    document.ewatch[ii]={};
    var we={
        watch_id:ii,
        ele:document.getElementById(id)
    };
    we.fun=callback;
    we.old=we.ele.innerHTML;
    we.watch_code=function(){
        var id=ii;
        var ee=document.ewatch[id];
        var new1=ee.ele.innerHTML;
        if(new1!=ee.old){
            we.fun(ee.old,new1);
            ee.old=new1;
            document.ewatch[id]=ee;
        }
    };
    document.ewatch[ii]=we;
    return {
        start:()=>{
            we.interval=setInterval(we.watch_code,100);
        },
        stop:()=>{
            try{
                clearInterval(we.interval);
            }catch(e){}
        }
    };
};
var e1=watchEle("ele_id",(oldc,newc)=>{
    alert("content change");
});
e1.start();
```

Attaches a watcher to an element, and watches the `innerHTML` content, and executes the callback on the event it changes.

For your question, you could change `.innerHTML` to `.value`